# Jquery: how to select next first element using class

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to auto fill city and state value after user typing 5-digit zip code. The Ajax part works perfectly, the problem is I have two sets of zip/city/state fields in one web page. I searched this issue for quite a while, using next(),nextAll() even slice(), none of them work in my situation.

#### Web page related part:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" class="style3">ZIP:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_ZIP" runat="server" Width="100px"
            alt="zip5" class="zip"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" class="style3">City: 
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_City" runat="server" Width="100px"
                class="city"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="style3">State:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_State" runat="server"
                    Width="100px" class="state"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="style2">ZIP:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_AffiOrComZIP" runat="server"
                    Width="100px" alt="zip5" class="zip"
                    ontextchanged="tb_AffiOrComZIP_TextChanged">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class="style2">City:</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_AffiOrParCity" runat="server"
                                Width="100px" class="city"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class="style2">State:</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_AffiOrParComState"
                                runat="server" Width="100px" class="state">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### JS:

```
$(".zip").each(function() {
    var zipTextBox = $(this);

    zipTextBox.keyup(function() {
        var zip = $(this).val();
        if (zip.length == 5) {
            $.post(rootPath + "/AjaxPages/DropdownData.aspx", {
                "inputValue": zip,
                "type": "zip"
            }, function(data) {
                var cityStr = $(data).attr("city");
                var stateStr = $(data).attr("state");
                $(this).nextAll(".city:first").val(cityStr); //this doesn't work
                for (var i = 0; i < $(this + ".state option").length; i++) { //this works for first
                    if ($(this + ".state").get(0).options[i].text == stateStr) {
                        $(this + ".state").get(0).options[i].selected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

After using Ajax function I get returned value for city and state. For each city textbox I give a "city" class, for each state dropdownlist I give a "state" class. I wonder how can I put those value into right position?  Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Indent code blocks with 4 spaces.

Comment: ...Please don't make me fix your question's formatting a third time. If you don't understand how to format, let someone else take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the elements with classes `zip` and `city` are not siblings. Try this:

```
$(".zip").keyup(function() {
    var zipTextBox = $(this),
        zip = zipTextBox.val();
    if (zip.length == 5) {
        $.post(rootPath + "/AjaxPages/DropdownData.aspx", {
            "inputValue": zip,
            "type": "zip"
        }, function(data) {
            var $data = $(data),
                cityStr = $data.attr("city"),
                stateStr = $data.attr("state"),
                zipTr = zipTextBox.closest('tr'),
                cityTr = zipTr.next(),
                stateTr = cityTr.next();

            cityTr.find('.city:first').val(cityStr);
            stateTr.find('input:select.state > option:contains(' + stateStr ')').attr('selected', true);
        });
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, you keep editing the markup in your question, so I'm taking a bit of a guess at the actual HTML you need to traverse.

Comment: Thank you Matt, it works perfectly. Thank you very much. BTW, I modified a little bit for the state part.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the :eq selector at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/